# StackedBar Chart highlighting complete single bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using StackedBar Chart in iOS-Charts, I need to provide two functionality:

1. When user selects single bar I need to highlight complete Bar
   instead of specific stack index.
2. I need to show pop-up with complete value.

How this can be achieved?

For highlighting I tried doing following but it's not working

```
let highlighter1: ChartHighlight = ChartHighlight(xIndex: dataSetIndex, dataSetIndex: 0, stackIndex: 0)
let highlighter2: ChartHighlight = ChartHighlight(xIndex: dataSetIndex, dataSetIndex: 0, stackIndex: 1)
let highlighter3: ChartHighlight = ChartHighlight(xIndex: dataSetIndex, dataSetIndex: 0, stackIndex: 2)

chartView.highlightValues([highlighter1, highlighter2, highlighter3])
```

if i give single value it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer can check in following link - https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/504

Answer (score 2):

1. To select complete stacked bar, you can use `chartView.setHighlightFullBarEnabled = true`
2. To show pop up, you can use ChartMarker, or else you can see ChartDemo-iOS of Charts github repo and use BalloonMarker.swift as an example.